# Images in ul wrapping on the side of larger image

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

[image]My page has a large image with text wrapping around it. I want 3 images on the bottom of the large image. But they keep wrapping on the side of the large image. I cannot figure out how to more them underneath the image. Here is my code:

```
<?php snippet('header') ?>
<div class="product">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h3><?= /** @var TYPE_NAME $page */
        $page->title() ?></h3>
      <?= $page->image()->resize(400) ?>
      <h5>Item Details</h5>
      <ul class="fieldList">
        <li>Item Code:&#9&#9&#9 <?= $page->Itemcode() ?></li>
        <li>Finish:&#9&#9&#9&#9 <?= $page->Finish() ?></li>
        <li>Color Range:&#9&#9 <?= $page->Colorrange() ?></li>
        <li>Material:&#9&#9&#9 <?= $page->Material() ?></li>
        <li>Size:&#9&#9&#9&#9 <?= $page->Size() ?></li>
        <li>Application:&#9&#9&#9 <?= $page->Application() ?></li>
        <li>Interior/Exterior:&#9 <?= $page->Interiorexterior() ?></li>
        <li>SF Per Cnt:&#9&#9&#9 <?= $page->Sfperctn() ?></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="container" class="clear">
        <div class="gallery-image">
          <ul>
            <?php
            $images = $page->gallery()->toFiles();
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
              <li> <?= $image->resize(150) ?></li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="clear">
        <h5>User Images</h5>
        <p>Get a feel of how the tiles will look in real life by viewing how our
          previous customers have implemented to enhance their space.</p>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <div class="clear" class="upload-image">
          <?php
          $images = $page->uploadedimages()->toFiles();
          ?>
          <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
            <li> <?= $image->resize(300) ?></li>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear" class="footer">
  <?php snippet('footer') ?>
</div>
```

and my css

```
/*.product .background {*/
/*  width: calc(100% - ((100% - 1180px) / 2));*/
/*  max-width: calc(80% - 4rem);*/
/*  height: calc(100% - 10rem);*/
/*  background: #F4F6F5;*/
/*  top: 0;*/
/*  z-index: -1;*/
/*  border-radius: 0px 320px 0px 0px;*/
/*  position: absolute;*/
/*}*/

.product .wrapper {
  padding: 5rem 4rem 4rem;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2rem 0rem 0;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.fieldList {
  font-family: fieldwork, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  /*font-size: 1rem;*/
  /*padding: 10px 0 30px 0;*/

}

.fieldList li {
  font-family: fieldwork, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: pre;

}

/*.item-details {*/
/*  font-family: fieldwork, sans-serif;*/
/*  font-weight: 500;*/
/*  font-size: 1.5rem;*/
/*  color: #2A4143;*/

/*}*/

h5 {
  font-family: fieldwork, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #2A4143;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;


}

.main-image {
  /*padding-bottom: 10px;*/
}

.gallery-image ul {
  display: flex;

}

.gallery-image li {
  padding-top: 30px;


}

.container {
  text-align: left;
}

.upload-image ul li {
  border: 1px solid #2A4143;
  display: inline;

}

.upload-image li:last-child {

  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Right now, my images are on the side of the large image, right underneath that ul list of items.

Comment: If you can, paste a screenshot of what you have now which might help visualize what you're trying to do.

Comment: also the HTML rendered (view source or inspector) ...

Comment: which part of inspect element should I snip @G-Cyrillus? the code is on top. what else would be helpful to see?

Comment: I added the entire page of code, as I have two other issues that are problematic 1) the pictures on the bottom are sticking to the footer even if I add a margin or padding 2) I need to have rounded corners for the images, but cannot seem to accomplish that 3) the first li displays with some of the text cut off. I've tried different things, but It's not accomplishing what I want.

Comment: I added the image @Bjorn.B

Answer (score 0):

What might work better here is defined separation of content into groups/sub-groups. I reorganized your html structure and css to be more flexible and allow you more control.

If you compare my code to yours,

- I basically grouped content into subgroups, and controlled them using flexbox vs floats. Just preference though. You could switch it to floats, but subgrouping is the most important factor here.
- If new content started on a new line like say the "User Images" title, then it was placed into a new container to manage and control that separation.

There's a million ways to do anything so you may find something else works for you beside what I've done. Visually grouping items into sub groups will allow you to have more control.

```css
.product {
  max-width: 1200px;
  font-family: fieldwork, sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem;
}
.product .flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-content: flex-end;
}
.product img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.product .left {
  width: 50%;
}
.product .right {
  width: 50%;
}
.product .right h5 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #2A4143;
  padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
  margin: 0;
}
.product .right ul.fieldList {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
  margin: 0;
}
.product .right ul.fieldList li {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  white-space: pre;
}
.product .right .gallery-image ul {
  display: flex;
}
.product .right .gallery-image ul li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.product .right .gallery-image ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.product .image-container ul.flex-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.product .image-container ul.flex-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.product .image-container ul.flex-container li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<?php snippet('header') ?>
<div class="product">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h3>8x24 Honex Blanco</h3>
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVybml0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <h5>Item Details</h5>
                <ul class="fieldList">
                    <li>Item Code:&#9&#9&#9 <?= $page->Itemcode() ?></li>
                    <li>Finish:&#9&#9&#9&#9<?= $page->Finish() ?></li>
                    <li>Color Range:&#9&#9<?= $page->Colorrange() ?></li>
                    <li>Material:&#9&#9&#9<?= $page->Material() ?></li>
                    <li>Size:&#9&#9&#9&#9<?= $page->Size() ?></li>
                    <li>Application:&#9&#9&#9<?= $page->Application() ?></li>
                    <li>Interior/Exterior:&#9<?= $page->Interiorexterior() ?></li>
                    <li>SF Per Cnt:&#9&#9&#9<?= $page->Sfperctn() ?></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="gallery-image">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img
                                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVybml0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
                        </li>
                        <li><img
                                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVybml0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
                        </li>
                        <li><img
                                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVybml0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h5>User Images</h5>
        <p>Get a feel of how the tiles will look in real life by viewing how our previous customers have implemented to enhance their space.</p>
        <div class="image-container">
            <ul class="flex-container">
                <li><img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVybml0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
                </li>
                <li><img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVybml0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
                </li>
                <li><img
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555041469-a586c61ea9bc?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8ZnVybml0dXJlfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Bjorn.B. I figured out my issues in the end. I have not reviewed your answer yet. But will do so when I get a minute and I'll post my solutions if they differ from yours. Thanks so much for your help.